# list of tables in my table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

So I'm working on some mathematical equations in my documents. I had issues to add a caption to my equation which made me define a few lines of code to define a custom "holder for my equations"

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\newaliascnt{eqfloat}{equation}
\newfloat{eqfloat}{h}{eqflts}
\floatname{eqfloat}{Equation}

\newcommand*{\ORGeqfloat}{}
\let\ORGeqfloat\eqfloat
\def\eqfloat{%
  \let\ORIGINALcaption\caption
  \def\caption{%
    \addtocounter{equation}{-1}%
    \ORIGINALcaption
  }%
  \ORGeqfloat
}
```

this is how I define my equations:

```
\begin{eqfloat}
\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\dot{x}\\
\dot{y}\\
\dot{z}\\
w_{x}\\
w_{y}\\
w_{z}
\end{array}\right] = J_{6 \times n} \left[\begin{array}{c}
\dot{q1}\\
\dot{q2}\\
\dots \\
\dot{qn}
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
\caption{Jacobian matrix of a robot arm with $n$ joints}
\end{eqfloat}
```

this is just an example so that the structure is clear.

and this is how it ends up looking:
[image]

Since it's something custom I'm confused as to how to make the list of equations.
I need it for the start of the document.

I have tried to make it in the front matter by doing:

```
\listof{eqfloat}{List of Equations}
```

but It doesn't show in my table of contents, how can I fix it. everything seems to be fine except the fact that my list of equations isn't in my Table of contents.
I tried:

```
\chapter{List of contents}
\listof{eqfloat}{}
```

but It makes the title of the chapter in one blank page then the list is on its own without a title in the next page.
Any help ? thank you very much

Comment: As you haven't provided a complete MWE that I can compile I'm not sure just what you are doing. You could try including `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Equations}` to put your list into the ToC like a chapter.

Comment: It would probably be better to reset the eqfloat counter each time than equivalence the two counters.  If you want a \listof(eqfloat} you will need to use a normal \caption.  `\setcounter{eqfloat}{\numexpr \value{equation)-1}`

Comment: The listof(eqfloat) works completely fine and shows up well in my document with the right names page numbers and even title. I just want to include it in my TOC.

Comment: I have added  `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Equations}` and it showed in the table of contents but when I click on the page number it doesn't take me anywhere. And now it's the same for the list of figures even though it was working before I try to add the list of equations.